# Firefox icon gone (since snap update?)

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, icons, snap

I can't find an firefox icon anymore since an scheduled update most probably via software-updater (I don't know the english name. German language package. I know I should switch to the English one)

The Firefox Icon was just gone. I do not remember exactly when, or what was the last thing I have done before. I only observed the task menu lacked an icon. I could still click on the blank area and firefox would open.

Now I am using some generic "web-browser" icon in the task bar.

I can only not find some `firefox.desktop` or `firefox.ico` file in my home directory.

Any idea what I can do?

I tried `snap refresh firefox` but it tells me there are not updates available for firefox.

Thanks

Comment: What do you see when you search for `firefox` in the menu? Can you start Firefox by typing `firefox`<enter>  in a terminal or in a run prompt (<Alt><F2>)? If not, then see what error message appears when you try to run `firefox`.